# how to get selected values from repeated dropdown list in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops

i am using loop to display a div based on user input

```
<% for (int i=0; i<Convert.ToInt32(Session["NumberOfPassengers"]); i++) {%>
<div class="some-class">

    <h4>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Add A Passenger "></asp:Label>
    </h4>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="First Name: " CssClass="labels"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Last Name: " CssClass="labels"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" CssClass="labels" Text="Class Type: "></asp:Label>
   
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Economy</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    
</div> <% }
```

how can i get the selected item for all drop down lists in C# code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Set the name attribute on your textboxs and dropdowns to be prefixed with Passenger[i]. E.g.

```
Passenger[0].FirstName
Passenger[0].LastName
Passenger[0].ClassType
Passenger[1].FirstName
Passenger[1].LastName
Passenger[1].ClassType
...
```

These will be posted as individual items in to Form collection. In MVC this can be automatically mapped to an array of Passenger object (for that to work the name must start at [0] ). Not sure in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

**This is a wrong way to use the asp controls inside the page.**

Placing the asp controls inside this loop

`<% for (int i=0; i<Convert.ToInt32(Session["NumberOfPassengers"]); i++) {%>`

**they are unable to create unique different ids** and so actually you can not get the correct post results - they neither been able to keep them after post. You must find other way to make that repeat - either manual render the controls with unique ids, either make custom control and repeat this one.

### as it is

For example - this code

```
        <% for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {%>            
        <br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Economy</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
        <%} %>
```

on post back will return that: `DropDownList1: Economy,Economy,Business,Economy,Business,Economy` - so its basic not a good way to find what control select and what - also all controls lose their selection because all they have the same id.

### Trick

I found a trick that you can do - you can change the id right after each loop - you can do something like...

```
 <% for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {%>            
  <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Economy</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Business</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <%
     ddlList.ID = "ddlList." + i;
  } %>
```

and now on post back you have this data

```
ddlList: Economy
ddlList.0: Economy
ddlList.1: Economy
ddlList.2: Business
ddlList.3: Economy
ddlList.4: Economy
```

You can read them using `Request.Form[]` - here's an example

```
    StringBuilder sbOnMe = new StringBuilder();

    string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
    {
        sbOnMe.Append(keys[i] + ": " + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "<br>");
    }
```

I do not recement this way because you lose the asp.net controls usability on code behind... but its a way.